# Probability - distribute people in a bus

Tags: probability, permutations

(a) In how many ways can 6 people be lined up to get on a bus? 
       **Answer = 6!** 
(b) If 3 speciﬁc persons, among 6, insist on following each other, how many ways are possible?
 **Answer = 4! * 3!**  
(c) If 2 speciﬁc persons, among 6, refuse to follow each other, how many ways are possible ? 
**Answer = 6! - 5! * 2**

I can't figure out how we got the answer of **part (c)**. May you explain how to think in order to solve such question

Comment: If you know how to do part (b) then change the parameters such that 2 persons insist on following each other.  Then you would subtract that from your answer in (a).

Comment: Ok, got your point 
Total - P(2 persons follow each other)' = Answer
Thank you @turkeyhundt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the sitting together ways from the total possible ways.
Let
$T = 6$ people be lined up to get on a bus is then the possible ways $= 6!$
$R = 2$ person want to stick together then the possible ways $= 2*5!$. If $2$ speciﬁc persons, among $6$, refuse to follow each other,then the possible ways are
$= T - R = 6! - 2*5!\ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 1):

(a) In how many ways can 6 people be lined up to get on a bus?
Answer = 6P6 = 6! = 720 ways

(b) If 3 speciﬁc persons, among 6, insist on following each other, how many ways are possible?
Answer = 4P4* 3P3 = 4! * 3!= 144 ways

(c) If 2 speciﬁc persons, among 6, refuse to follow each other, how many ways are possible ?
Answer = 6P6 - 5P5 * 2P2 = 6! - 5! * 2 = 480 ways

Answer (score 0):

If we have 6 persons, then there are 6! = 720 possible ways to arrange them in a line without any restrictions. However, if 2 specific persons refuse to follow each other, then we need to consider two cases:

**Case 1:**
The two specific persons are next to each other.
If the two specific persons are next to each other, then we can treat them as a single unit and arrange the remaining 5 units in a line. There are 5! = 120 ways to do this. However, the two specific persons can switch places within their unit, so there are actually 2 ways to arrange them within their unit. Therefore, there are 120 * 2 = 240 possible ways in this case.

**Case 2:**
The two specific persons are not next to each other.
If the two specific persons are not next to each other, then we can arrange the remaining 4 persons in a line first, which can be done in 4! = 24 ways. Then we can insert the two specific persons into the line, which can be done in 5 different positions (before the first person, between the first and second person, etc.). Therefore, there are 24 * 5 = 120 possible ways in this case.

Overall, there are 240 + 120 = 360 possible ways for the 6 persons to line up if 2 specific persons refuse to follow each other.